# update col value on the basis of rule

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table having value and colrank column, value is value of particular id and rank is percentrank of particular id in whole records.

I want to update records on 2 conditions like

1. where colrank is more than 0.95 then update value to value of nearest colrank respective value of <=0.95
2. where colrank is less then 0.5 then update value to value of nearset colrank respective value of >=0.5

   ```
   declare @tbl table (id int , value float , colrank float );

   insert into @tbl
   values(1,10, 0.52),
         (2,11, 0.48),
         (3,18, 0.94),
         (4,22, 0.96);

   select * from @tbl;
   ```

my code is below but i am not satisfied becuase i am using same table multiple times.Please suggest what is the best way.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT MAX(colrank ) high 
FROM @tbl 
where   colrank <= 0.95
), 
cte1 as (
SELECT min(colrank ) low 
FROM @tbl 
where   colrank <= 0.5
)  

select * from cte ,cte1
```

Comment: can you post sample output please?

Answer (score 2):

you can use conditional aggregation to avoid double iteration under the same dataset:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN colrank <= 0.95 THEN colrank END) high,
       MIN(CASE WHEN colrank <= 0.5 THEN colrank END) low 
FROM @tbl;
```

[**DEMO**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=deaeec063354bcea8056b96fbdffda9e)

Answer (score 2):

This was fun. I tried and I understand that this might not be best solution, still posting as it is satisfying all scenario: [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad550/1)

```
create table tbl (id int , value float , colrank float );
insert into tbl
values(1,10, 0.52),
      (2,11, 0.54),
      (3,12, 0.48),
      (4,13, 0.49),
      (5,17, 0.93),
      (6,18, 0.94),
      (7,22, 0.96);

WITH CTE AS
( (SELECT TOP 1 *,1 as [rank] from tbl WHERE colrank < 0.95 ORDER BY colrank DESC)
   UNION
  (SELECT TOP 1 *,2 as [rank] from tbl WHERE colrank > 0.50 ORDER BY colrank ASC)
 )
  SELECT 
    b.id, b.value, b.colrank, a.value
  FROM 
    tbl b 
  LEFT JOIN cte a
  ON 
    (CASE WHEN b.colrank < 0.5 and a.[rank] = 2 THEN 1
        WHEN b.colrank > 0.95 and a.[rank] = 1 THEN 1
    END) = 1
  WHERE a.value IS NOT NULL
```

to update simply replace select with update syntax like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
( (SELECT TOP 1 *,1 as [rank] from tbl WHERE colrank < 0.95 ORDER BY colrank DESC)
   UNION
  (SELECT TOP 1 *,2 as [rank] from tbl WHERE colrank > 0.50 ORDER BY colrank ASC)
 )
  UPDATE b
  SET b.value = a.value
  FROM 
    tbl b 
  LEFT JOIN cte a
  ON 
    (CASE WHEN b.colrank < 0.5 and a.[rank] = 2 THEN 1
        WHEN b.colrank > 0.95 and a.[rank] = 1 THEN 1
    END) = 1
  WHERE a.value IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple `UPDATE` with `CASE` statement will work in this scenario. Try query like following.

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Value =
   (
      CASE WHEN T.colrank > 0.95 THEN (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM @tbl T1
                         WHERE T1.colrank <= 0.95 ORDER BY T1.colrank DESC)
      WHEN T.colrank < 0.5 THEN (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM @tbl T2 
                         WHERE T2.colrank >= 0.5 ORDER BY T2.colrank)
      ELSE T.value
      END
   )
FROM @tbl T
```

[**DEMO**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6663ea60a27068de4801d49195efc217)

Answer (score 0):

This is two updates but it is still efficient.

```
declare @tbl table (id int , value float , colrank float );
insert into @tbl
values(1, 10, 0.52),
      (2, 11, 0.48),
      (3, 18, 0.94),
      (4, 22, 0.96);
declare @min float = (select min(colrank) from @tbl where colrank >= 0.5);
declare @max float = (select max(colrank) from @tbl where colrank <= 0.95);
select * from @tbl;
update @tbl set colrank = @min where colrank < @min;
update @tbl set colrank = @max where colrank > @max;
select * from @tbl;

id          value                  colrank
----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           10                     0.52
2           11                     0.48
3           18                     0.94
4           22                     0.96

id          value                  colrank
----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           10                     0.52
2           11                     0.52
3           18                     0.94
4           22                     0.94
```